# Don't know how to use cmake for successful linking, if subdirectory folder is inside another subdirectory

Tags: gcc, cmake, directory, nested

linker cannot link the exe, here my simplified setup:

```
TOP_LEVEL
├───app1
|   └───CMakeLists.txt
|   └───MYBUILD
├───stdModA
|       └───CMakeLists.txt
└───stdModB
|   └───2
|        └───CMakeLists.txt
└types.h

All command are executed inside app1 folder.
```

app1/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(app1 LANGUAGES C CXX)

list(APPEND APP_SRCS "main.c")

# the used modules in this application
list(APPEND MODS "stdModA")
list(APPEND MODS "stdModB/2")

foreach(MOD IN LISTS MODS)
  add_subdirectory(../${MOD} MYBUILD/${MOD})  
endforeach()

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}.elf ${APP_SRCS})

foreach(MOD IN LISTS MODS)
  target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}.elf PUBLIC ../${MOD})
endforeach()

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}.elf PUBLIC ${MODS})
```

stdModA/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
set(MOD_NAME "stdModA")
add_library(${MOD_NAME} STATIC stdModA.c)
target_include_directories(${MOD_NAME} PUBLIC ../app1)
```

stdModB/2/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
set(MOD_NAME "2")
add_library(${MOD_NAME} STATIC stdModB.c)
target_include_directories(${MOD_NAME} PUBLIC ../.. )
```

Linker error:

```
FAILED: app1.elf
cmd.exe /C "cd . && c:\gcc\bin\gcc.exe  CMakeFiles/app1.elf.dir/main.c.obj -o app1.elf  MYBUILD/stdModA/libstdModA.a  -lstdModB/2 && cd ."
c:/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/gcc/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lstdModB/2
```

Please don't comment on strange directory structure in embedded builddir.

Played around with various setups. MYBUILD contains:

```
MYBUILD
└───MYBUILD
    ├───stdModA
    │   └───libstdModA.a
    │   └───CMakeFiles
    │       └───stdModA.dir
    └───stdModB
        └───2
            └───lib2.a
            └───CMakeFiles
                └───2.dir
```

Comment: In `stdModA/CMakeLists.txt` you create a target named `stdModA`. In `stdModB/2/CMakeLists.txt` you create a target named `2` (!). There is no target `stdModB/2` which you link with in the `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. What do you mean by target? The lib2.a or something else?

Comment: "target" is created with `add_library` or `add_executable` call, name of the created target is specified as the first argument of that call. If your project creates a library using `add_library`, then for link with that library you just need to pass target name to the `target_link_libraries` command.

Comment: So you mean the problem is that the MODS variable contains "stdModB/2"? It expects just "2" in the target_link_libraries()? Yes you are right...if I put the name without folder into it, it works. But

Comment: @Tsyvarev you mean the problem is that the MODS variable contains "stdModB/2"? It expects just "2" in the target_link_libraries()? Yes you are right...if I put the name without folder into it, it works. But how can I make my life comfortable by just adding/removing **list(APPEND MODS "stdModB/2")**?